# gqlgen Set cookie from resolver

Tags: go, go-gin, gqlgen

I'm using gin and gqlgen.
I was need to set cookie from resolver but all I have in my resolver is context and inputs from graphQL.
This question is already answered in [github](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen/issues/567).
But this one is different because I can't change `ctx.Writer.Write` and nothing when you try to pass in `ctx.Next`. because `gin` does not work like that.

```
func (r *mutationResolver) Login(ctx context.Context, email string, password string) (bool, error) {
        // You need ctx.Writer to set a cookie and can't access that from here
}
```

I have solved this issue and I want to answer my own question below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Explanation

#### [How serverside cookie works:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)

Server-side cookies are embedded within the response headers by the server, signaling to the browser its intent to set a cookie. This mechanism aims to enable the utilization of `ctx.Writer` directly within the resolver, bypassing the need for middleware intervention.

In the middleware, you are provided with a context (`ctx`) that contains `ctx.Request.Context()`. You also have access to `ctx.Writer`, which is necessary for modifying headers to set cookies. To make `ctx.Writer` available in your resolver, you should embed it within `ctx.Request.Context()`. This approach is essential because only the `ctx.Request` is passed to your resolver, not the entire context (`ctx`).

## The code

This struct will use to create in the middleware and pass a pointer of it to the resolver, in all the routes you will know if a user is authenticated or not, and also will be able to use the `http.ResponseWriter`

### Struct

```golang
type CookieAccess struct {
    Writer     http.ResponseWriter
    IsLoggedIn bool
    UserId     uint64
}
```

### Middleware

```golang
func setValInCtx(ctx *gin.Context, val interface{}) {
    newCtx := context.WithValue(ctx.Request.Context(), "ctxCookieAccessKey", val)
    ctx.Request = ctx.Request.WithContext(newCtx)
}

func Middleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        cookieA := CookieAccess{
            Writer: ctx.Writer,
            IsLoggedIn: false, // Assume not logged in by default
            UserId: 0,
        }

        setValInCtx(ctx, &cookieA)

        c, err := ctx.Request.Cookie("tokenKey")
        if err != nil {
            // If there's an error fetching the cookie, log it and proceed
            log.Printf("Error fetching 'tokenKey' cookie: %v", err)
            ctx.Next()
            return
        }

        // Proceed with token parsing only if the cookie is successfully fetched
        rawToken := c.Value
        userId, err := ParseToken(rawToken)
        if err != nil {
            // If there's an error parsing the token, log it and ensure user is not logged in
            log.Printf("Error parsing token: %v", err)
        } else {
            // If token is successfully parsed, mark user as logged in and set UserId
            cookieA.IsLoggedIn = true
            cookieA.UserId = userId
        }

        ctx.Next()
    }
}
```

### Resolvers

```golang
func (r *MutationResolver) logginOrConsumerResolver(ctx context.Context, input Credentials) (*Response, error) {
    // ctx.Request.Context() from middleware is here
    ca := ctx.Value("ctxCookieAccessKey").(*CookieAccess)
    if ca.IsLoggedIn {
        // this is the way to get token proceed result in other resolvers
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("you are already have a valid token, userId: %v", ca.userId)
    }

    http.SetCookie(ca.Writer, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "tokenKey",
        Value:    token, // make your token
        HttpOnly: true,
        Path:     "/",
        Expires:  time.Now().Add(24 * time.Hour),
    })

    return nil, nil
}
```